# VSTS deployment not working properly

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've got .Net solution Built in VSTS. My Release also succeeded but I'm not able to see my WebApplication running. Find the screenshot attached[image: WebApp Screenshot]

Please find my Deploy azure app service task screenshot attached . [image]

Please suggest if i miss any configuration.

Comment: Logs from your release would help, if it succeeded, but your app service doesn't appear updated, it probably went somewhere, but not where you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your package or folder to deploy in **Deploy Azure App Service** task is pointed to drop folder. Instead it should be pointed to zip file inside the drop folder.

Eg: ***$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestApp/drop/TestApp.zip***

Try this and update if any other issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is the content of **hostingstart.html**, which is in the **wwwroot** folder of app service, you can check the files by accessing `https://[web app name].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and go to `site\wwwroot` folder.

If the app service can’t recognize the web project (e.g. Global.asax) and there aren’t the default page files (Web service **Application settings**.), it will display hosttingstart.html page)

So, you need to check the files in release artifact.

If it is the web deploy package (zip file), you need to publish it through **Web Deploy**. (Check **Publish using Web Deploy** option and specify package path in Package or folder box (e.g. `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`), you can clear additional files by checking **Remove additional files at destination** option)